# String decorator class leads to numerous build errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I've created a decorator class for std::string that, when included in the project, causes thousands of build errors originating from files such as cmath.h, cstring.h, xstring.h and I cant figure out why. All files in the project that need string operations use this class instead of std::string for consistency.

I've tried to slowly comment out parts of the decorator class to try to make sense of what is actually happening, but the errors only started to make sense once the entire class had been commented out. There are too many errors to list them all here, but a small sample of the errors include:

```
Error   C2733   'abs': second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed
Error   C2065   'allocator': undeclared identifier
Error   C2974   'std::basic_string': invalid template argument for '_Alloc'
Error   C2873   'strxfrm': symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
Error   C2535   'void std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::_Construct(_Iter,_Iter)': member function already defined or declared
```

There are thousands of these errors across multiple standard library files. this is the header file for the string decorator:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace Framework
{
    class String
    {
    private:
        std::string Data;

    public:
        String();
        String(const char*Init);
        String(int Init);

        friend String operator+(String &LHS, String &RHS);  
        friend String operator+(String &LHS, const char *RHS);
        friend String operator+(String &LHS, const char RHS);

        String& operator+=(String &RHS);
        String& operator+=(const char *RHS);
        String& operator+=(const char RHS);

        friend bool operator==(String &LHS, String &RHS);
        friend bool operator==(const String &LHS, const String &RHS);
        friend bool operator==(String &LHS, const char *RHS);
        friend bool operator==(const String &LHS, const char *RHS);

        friend bool operator!=(String &LHS, String &RHS);
        friend bool operator!=(const String &LHS, const String &RHS);
        friend bool operator!=(String &LHS, const char *RHS);

        String& operator=(const char * RHS);

        char operator[](int Index);

        size_t Length();
        size_t IndexOf(String SubString, size_t Offset = 0);

        bool Contains(String SubString, size_t Offset = 0);         
        String SubString(size_t Start, size_t Count = 0);           
        std::vector<String> Split(char Delimeter, bool KeepEmpty = false);

        const char *ToCharString();

        void Insert(int Position, String Text);
        void RemoveAt(int Index);

        int ToInt();
        double ToDouble();          
        bool ToBoolean();
        unsigned __int8 ToByte();
    };      
}
```

What makes this more baffling is the fact that this facade worked perfectly in another project, its only in this new project that it seems to be failing.

Comment: What you've posted compiles for me with Visual Studio but obviously what you've posted is not a complete example so who knows what's in the code we can't see.  Are you able to compile other things?

Comment: Yeah the project is large and complex with a lot of moving parts. I am able to compile other projects that use the same decorator class. But in this instance, its one project thats using it and it won't compile.

Comment: If this code works in another project then it seems like this code is not the problem, something else is.

Comment: If I had to guess: the project where this code doesn't work defines `String` (or some other name used in your class) as a macro.

Comment: What made me think this was the root of the problem was, before I added the file to the project, the build errors were about Framework::String being missing, after adding the String.h and String.cpp files, it starting spitting out thousands of those bizarre errors.

Comment: Okay yeah I'm now more convinced then ever, the String.h and String.cpp files are to blame. I just removed all references to Framework::String and reverted all string use back to std::string, I then commented out all lines of code that used any extension method Framework::String provided. I then removed the String.h and String.cpp files and the project now builds and runs fine. If I add the String.h and String.cpp files back again the errors return, even if the files have all their code commented out :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what caused this issue, but the resolution of it was moving the String.h and String.cpp files to a sub folder in the project instead of letting it sit at the root of the project. Once I had done that and reverted everything back to using Framework::String, the project built fine.

A clue as to why this worked may be in the fact that if I right clicked on a `#include "String.h"` line when String.h and String.cpp were still in the root directory and selected Open Document, it opened the standard library string.h file instead of my String.h file.

Comment: Had similar errors for these 3 lines in an old header:
#define nullptr NULL
void * operator new (uint32_t size);
void operator delete (void * p);